# Javascript new keyword - code explanation request

Tags: javascript

Can you please explain the following piece of code, ? it is working in my browser console. So how does this work ? The new keyword doesnt create a new instance at all or how is it ?

```
 var myObject = new Object(); // Produces an Object() object.
    myObject['0'] = 'f';
    myObject['1'] = 'o';
    myObject['2'] = 'o';
    console.log(myObject); // Logs Object { 0="f", 1="o", 2="o"}

    var myString = new String('foo'); // Produces a String() object.
    console.log(myString); // Logs foo { 0="f", 1="o", 2="o"
```

Please explain.

Comment: What makes you think that the new keyword doesn't create a new instance?

Comment: @Quentin I don't think he thinks that the new keyword doesn't create a new instance; he doesn't know what it does and was offering that as a possible explanation.

Comment: @Quentin - i am not thinking new keyword wont create a new instance as funkybro says. if its a new instance how does it carry the value of myObject onto myString variable. little confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if its a new instance how does it carry the value of myObject onto myString variable

It doesn't. You are initialising your String object with a string literal:

```
new String('foo');
```

That *foo* is an entirely different *foo* to the characters you assign to the three properties of the object. For comparison, [replace the second foo with bar](http://jsfiddle.net/AExQP/).

Comment: Ya you are right, So it means that String object stores the values assigned in kind of an array.. so thats why myString[0] === 'f'; myString[1] === 'o';myString[2] === 'o'.. is my assumption correct?

Answer (score 0):

It's completely normal behavior:

`new String` creates an `Object`, if you will type `"var myString = new String('moo')"`, you will get another object with different values.

[https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/#se‌​ction_7](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/#se%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bction_7)

Comment: i just went thru the page.Couldnt find an explanation for the above scenario. can you please help finding.?

Comment: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/#section_7](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/#section_7)

**new String** creates **an Object**, if you will type "var myString = new String('moo')", you will get another object with different values.